# Anonymous space between two floated li elements

Tags: html, css, html-lists, border

I'm creating header of one aplication nad I found strange problem, which never happentd to me before. The problem is, that i have two list inside header, one floated to left, one to right and between all li elements there are two types of border. That's ok, but there's creating space between them out of nowhere? Or at least, I can't find what is creating the space

Can someone tell me where's space created?

Here is jsFiddle: [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/x5qYd/)

Or direct-input:

HTML:

```
<header id="header">

<ul class="left">
    <li class="title">jedna</li>
    <li class="new-task">dva</li>
    <li class="new-comment">NC</li>
</ul>

<ul class="right">
    <li class="logged">jedna  </li>
    <li class="logout"><a href="#">dva</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
header
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    min-height: 35px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#bbbbbb), to(#efefef));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #bbbbbb);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #bbbbbb);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #bbbbbb);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #bbbbbb);


}

header ul
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 35px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

header ul li
{
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}

header ul li:first-of-type
{
    border-left: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

header ul li:last-of-type
{
    border-right: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

header ul.left
{
    float: left;
}

header ul.right
{
    float:right;
}
```

EDIT:

This space:

[image: space]

Comment: What "space" are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `li`'s are set to `display: inline`, so your browser is putting a space between each `li` just like it would between words. You can counter this default behavior in a few ways. You can `float` instead of using `display: inline`, you can put all your `li`'s on one line without spaces, or you can add a negative margin to pull the `li`'s together. This article explains your options better than I could:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: beat me to the punch - you ought to set those elements to float if you want each li to sit flush next to one another.

Comment: I posted this exact article and info 6 minutes ago... A paragraph is nice but a little more info would go a lot further.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float: left;` and reduce `padding`, here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/bM9kw/)**</kbd>

```
header ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
```

*Note: Horizontal space with width of about 4px is always added on `inline` & `inline-block` elements and to fix that you must `float` them or write HTML code in line for that elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by the `display: inline;`.

What is happening is the white space between the `lis` is being considered as a character.

To prevent this add `font-size: 0;` to the parent `ul` and then add the `font-size: 16px;` to the `lis`.

```
header ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 35px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0;
}

header ul li {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/x5qYd/1/)

Here is a good [article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) on what options you can use.

Comment: Using `font-size: 0` is the worst possible technique for suppressing whitespace.

Comment: @cimmanon Can you please explain to me why? `margin: -4px;` is the worst possible way. And while we are on this, this way allows your code to stay clean and easy to read while removing any whitespace.

Comment: You mean other than the fact that it doesn't work with relative font-sizes?  Ok, it doesn't work in Android at all.  It doesn't work in Presto versions of Opera, either, which are still more widely used than Blink versions by a very significant margin.

Comment: @cimmanon That's a good thing to point out but I would not say this is "the worst possible technique for suppressing whitespace". Everyone has their own opinions so thank you for pointing that out. This may not be good for those options you added but those options are not every option on the web. That is also why I added an article full of other options.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ul li` to `float:left;` and set the `line-height` to 25 instead of 35 in `header ul`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following CSS code fixed it for me:

```
header ul.left li {
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```